# GUI localisation by development stage

Tags: xml, localization, lazarus, freepascal

I'm writing software that should be free for many users of the world. And I wants provide a chance for users (community) to traslate any locale for GUI themself. I don't think that it's good idea to embed any locales in binary release or libraries (such as *.dll, *.so, etc). Lazarus + Free Pascal 3.0.2. Some components (textlables, menuitems for example) have names and captions properties. I plan to make an XML files (lang_en.xml, lang_de.xml, etc), which contains 'key:value' attributes, like:

```
<tag name="ComponentName" value="ComponentCaption" />
```

, and takes it from file to assign components of program by runtime.  That's my questions:

1. The solutions of problem are satisfactory? If not, what information you recommended to reading for more perfect realisation of custom localisation?
2. I have some doubt about saving `Component.Name` values in binary program after aggresive optimizations. If it's true, which another pairs key:value type I must use?

Answer (score 1):

Adding LCLTranslator or DefaultTranslator to the uses clause of your main form, declaring strings as resourcestrings, and activating the i18n option in the project settings are often enough to make your program translatable (well, 90%... - some tweaking needed here and there)

Have a look at the tutorial http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Step-by-step_instructions_for_creating_multi-language_applications which explains how to use the Lazarus localization system based on po files. The general concept is explained in [http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Translations_/*i18n*/_localizations_for_programs](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Translations_/_i18n_/_localizations_for_programs). Find a working example in the folder *examples/translation* of you Lazarus installation.

Comment: Thank you. As I understand, the way of you recommended is design-time localisation, and machine translate. Seems It's not the way what I want to do. I need runtime localisation and hads on translate. Simply abstract Bob Jons open lang_en.xml, change eng values on hindu and save its as lang_hi.xml. By runtime program parse directory (if not set default lang) and reading headers all xml files `<locale value="english" />` example. That's enough.

Comment: Machine translate? No, I think we are pretty close. Using a translation tool, like poedit, we translate all translatable strings in "project.po" to a new language, e.g. "project.it,po" for Italian. Then at runtime, the program loads the correct language file and replaces the original texts by the translated ones. The only difference seems to me that we don't use xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik Lazarus has an own gettext implementation under the hood that directly reads .po which are textual.

Your solution is zero order, and needs lots of additional refinement and thinking. Some things to think about to get started:

1. Componentname is only unique within a form, so you need at least a level to differ from similar forms.
2. differently named componentnames might need the same text.
3. text in the original language might use the same word for things that are different in one of the translated languages. There should be a way to override.
4. gettext has support for multiples (one cow, two cows, three cows) in multiple languages. Some use a different suffix for "two" as for "more"

At the very least start studying what is there (the lazarus translation system and the gettext it gets some of its principles of) and the design reasons behind that.

Mor